# How can I retrieve the ID of the clicked button from the method handling this event into a SharePoint 2013 Web Part?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am pretty new in **.NET** and **SharePoint** (I am working on SharePoint 2013) and I have the following problem developing a **Web Part**.

Into my Web Part I have this **ImageButton**:

```
ImageButton btnApplica = new ImageButton();
btnApplica.ToolTip = "Documento in Entrata";
btnApplica.Click += btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta;
btnApplica.ID = "btnEntrata";
btnApplica.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/15/images/MyProject/Default/Ribbon/DocEntrataRibbon.png";
```

As you can see this clicking on this button is performed the **btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta()** method, this one:

```
void btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta START");

    SPWeb contextWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    string url = contextWeb.Url;

    string link = url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Carica documento.aspx?mode=scelta_campi_facoltativi_etichetta&obj=" + obj;

    SPUtility.Redirect(link, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context);

}
```

It works fine. My problem is: from the inside of this **btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta(object sender, EventArgs e)** method can I retrieve the clicked button? The **ID** (iin this case the **btnEntrata** value) should be perfect.

I want to use this method to handle the click on different buttons instead create a new method for each button.

Can I do something like this? How can I retrieve the ID of the clicked button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the sender variable to a button and then get the ID for example:

```
void btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta START");
    ImageButton btnApplica = (ImageButton) sender;
    String idBtn = btnApplica.ID;

    SPWeb contextWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    string url = contextWeb.Url;

    string link = url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Carica documento.aspx?mode=scelta_campi_facoltativi_etichetta&obj=" + obj;

    SPUtility.Redirect(link, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"object sender" is a generic object that represents the object that are calling the method, in this case ImageButton. You can't directly access sender's class variables, because "object" is pretty much a placeholder for any object. To be able to access your objects variables, you can cast it to the object you are expecting.

```
void btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("btnApplica_Click_Scelta_Campi_Etichetta START");
    string id;
    if(sender.GetType() == typeof(ImageButton))
    {
       ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender; // This is a cast
       id = button.ID;
    }
    SPWeb contextWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    string url = contextWeb.Url;

    string link = url + "/ARXEIA WEBPART/Carica documento.aspx?mode=scelta_campi_facoltativi_etichetta&obj=" + obj;

    SPUtility.Redirect(link, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context);

}
```